# How to get rid of double cycle windows prompt in XFCE

Tags: xfce, multi-monitor

I am currently using a dual monitor setup. When cycling through windows (alt+tab) the prompt for cycling appears on both monitors at the same time, showing the same thing. Is there any way to adjust the XFCE settings to make this appear only on the main monitor (in my case monitor 0)?